# How to implement flux architecture in multipage application?

Tags: javascript, flux

I want to design a multipage application but i also want to use flux architecture for the application.
I know how to implement flux is a single page application. 
What i'm thinking is:

1. Client browser sent request to URl, request handled by golang server
2. Golang server send html with embedded javascript
3. This javascript file will implment flux
4. User clicks an event, dispaches action by sending a request to the server using jQuery
5. Server handles request

If you navigate to different URL, different html + javascript will be sent back to client

Does anyone know if this is a good or bad way to implement flux?

Comment: You already have different implementations of flux available. You can get more info 

https://medium.com/social-tables-tech/we-compared-13-top-flux-implementations-you-won-t-believe-who-came-out-on-top-1063db32fe73

http://jamesknelson.com/which-flux-implementation-should-i-use-with-react/

Comment: Is there anything wrong with thise approach though?

Comment: What I am saying is **Why to implement flux yourself, when you already have a solution**?

Comment: Essentially what you;re saying is dont reinvent the wheel. But does something exists for implementing flux across both client and server?